# Exception when using @SchemaValidation annotation on JAX-WS endpoint in Weblogic

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee, weblogic, jax-ws

I am trying to get schema validation working for a JAX-WS Web Service deployed on Weblogic 10.3.3.

According to the documentation, this should be as simple as adding the annotation 
"@SchemaValidation" to the endpoint class. However when I try this the following exception is thrown when the application is deployed:

```
Caused by: javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: 
Annotation@com.sun.xml.internal.ws.developer.SchemaValidation 
(handler=class com.sun.xml.internal.ws.server.DraconianValidationErrorHandler)
is not recognizable, 
atleast one constructor of class com.sun.xml.internal.ws.developer.SchemaValidationFeature 
should be marked with @FeatureConstructor
at com.sun.xml.ws.binding.WebServiceFeatureList.getWebServiceFeatureBean(WebServiceFeatureList.java:169)
at com.sun.xml.ws.binding.WebServiceFeatureList.parseAnnotations(WebServiceFeatureList.java:141)
```

The error message is complaining that "com.sun.xml.internal.ws.developer.SchemaValidationFeature" does not have a constructor annotated with @FeatureConstructor. When I look at that class, it sure seems to have one:

```
  @com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.FeatureConstructor(value={"handler"})
  public SchemaValidationFeature(java.lang.Class arg0);
```

I have googled around but cannot find any reference to this more than [this](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=14480007) fellow unfortunate soul who did not get any answers. It would be great if someone could point me in the right direction because at this moment I am stuck.

Answer (score 1):

`SchemaValidation` annotation is working, but make sure you're importing correct class.

`com.sun.xml.ws.developer.SchemaValidation`

instead of

`com.sun.xml.internal.ws.developer.SchemaValidation`

The second class is bundled with JDK by default. The first one (used by weblogic) comes from `glassfish.jaxws.rt_XXX.jar`, so you may need to add this jar to your classpath explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same problem recently.

To overcome this, I added the tag

`<validation-request>true</validation-request>`

to the file  weblogic-webservices.xml

This enabled SOAP request validation on the app-server.

[XML Structure of weblogic-webservices.xml](http://docs.oracle.com/docs/cd/E12840_01/wls/docs103/webserv_ref/dd.html)

Note : I have not been able to use the @SchemaValidation tag successfully, but the above  way - works as expected.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Nishant. However, I was for some reason not able to get Weblogic to read the webservices descriptor. I ended up writing my own validation logic using a SoapHandler which may have been just as well as I need to be able to turn validation on and off by configuration.